# Expresso Store: products listing with prices (in modifiers)

Tags: expresso-store, modifiers, price-modifier

I have a product listing page which displays product title and product image as well product price. Part of the code related to product price looks like:

```
{if status == "retail"}
    {exp:store:product entry_id="{entry_id}" disable_form="yes"}
        <span class="store_product_price">{price}</span>
        {if total_stock == 0}<br /><span class="store_product_out_of_stock">Sold Out</span>{/if}
    {/exp:store:product}
{/if}
```

and it works for product without modifiers.

My question is how can I display product price which is stored as modifiers as product price range, something like $200-$400 (lowers - highest price)? I have try to use `price_inc_mod` within `{modifier_options}` and store all prices as an array, but somehow that last step wasn't working for me.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got this to work. Below code example

```
{exp:store:product entry_id="{entry_id}" disable_form="yes"}

<?php  $prices = array(); ?>
{modifiers}
{modifier_options}
    <?php $prices[] = str_replace('$', '', str_replace(' ', '', str_replace(',', '','{price_inc_mod}'))) ;?>
{/modifier_options}
{/modifiers}
<?php 
sort($prices);
?>
<span class="store_product_price"><?php echo $prices[0]; ?></span>
{/exp:store:product}
```

Comment: You should be able to do it without php in your templates.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to do it without using PHP in your template you would be able to use the `{modifier_option}` tag pair along with some [conditional](https://www.exp-resso.com/docs/product_tag.html#if_option_first)s to get the price to display properly.

```
{if status == "retail"}
    {exp:store:product entry_id="{entry_id}" disable_form="yes"}
        <span class="store_product_price">
          {modifiers}
            {if modifier_options} 
                {modifier_options}
                    {!-- 
                     --- use price_inc_mod if your items dont have tax
                     --- use price_inc_mod_inc_tax if you have tax inclusive pricing
                    --}
                    {if option_first}{price_inc_mod}{/if}{if option_last} - {price_inc_mod}{/if}
                {/modifier_options}
              {/modifiers}
            {else}
                {price}
            {/if}
            </span>
        {if total_stock == 0}<br /><span class="store_product_out_of_stock">Sold Out</span>{/if}
    {/exp:store:product}
{/if}
```

That should get it sorted out for you as long as the first and last modifiers have the the lowest and highest prices respectively.

Comment: Well, that code is not accurate and depends on how store owner will add modifier options (in this case first price must be always lowest one and last one higher). Also `{modifier_options}` must be wrapped with `{modifiers}` other way it is not working at all.

Comment: I have updated my code to include the modifiers tag pair