# Expresso-store: Shpping rule and descrtiption

Tags: expresso-store, shipping

Is it possible to display related description from shipping rule at the checkout process for particular shipping method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to use the [Shipping Method](https://www.exp-resso.com/docs/checkout_tag.html#shipping_methods) tag pair to loop through available shipping methods. You will want to look `shipping_method_name`, `shipping_method_class,`method_title`, and`method_price` tags in particular.

Comment: Great! Can you take a look at that one as DevDemon support looks to be dead: http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/26925/expresso-store-products-listing-with-prices-in-modifiers